# how to show (style) xml product feed into php

Tags: php, css, xml

I would like to show the content of an xml file in a way that it shows the title, image, price and button with external link to the website.

Construction of the xml:

```
 <title>
 <![CDATA[ here comes the title ]]>
 </title>
 <description>
 <![CDATA[ here you can find the description of the product. ]]>
 </description>
 <link>https://www.linktoproduct.com</link>
 <g:product_type>
 <![CDATA[ brand1 &gt; brand2 &gt; brand3 &gt; brand ]]>
 </g:product_type>
 <g:image_link>https://www.linktoproduct.com/imageproduct.jpg</g:image_link>
 <g:price>
 <![CDATA[ 35.10 EUR ]]>
 </g:price>
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
 <?php
 $xml_data =    simplexml_load_file("https://www.website.com/productfeed.xml") or 
 die("Error: Object Creation failure");

 foreach ($xml_data->children() as $data)
 {
 echo "<div class='col-md-4'>";
 echo "<div class='title'>$data->title</div>";
 echo "<a href='$data->link' target='_blank'><div class='link'></div></a>";
 echo "</div>";
 }
 ?>
```

but it gives me this issue on how to show the price and image: in the xml it is named "<g:price>" which is different than the other ones (no "g:")

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: focussing on one issue now, @brombeer

Comment: Why did you remove your other/same question, I believe someone posted a link that would help? What has changed?

Comment: Someone had closed the other thread ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this type of tag <g:product_type> have namespace, and you should access this namespace with "children" to get their data. For simple, if your namespace was :

```
http://base.google.com/ns/1.0
```

you need to use code like this:

```
<?php
 
$xml_data = simplexml_load_file("https://www.example.com/list.xml") or die("Error: Object Creation failure");
foreach ($xml_data->children() as $data) {
    
    $ns_data = $data->children("http://base.google.com/ns/1.0");
    
    echo "<div class='col-md-4'>";
    echo "<div class='title'>$data->title</div>";
    echo "<div class='price'>$ns_data->price</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks @hanif. I added your code, but it doesn't do the trick:
<?php
$xml_data = simplexml_load_file("https://www.website.com/productfeed.xml") or 
die("Error: Object Creation failure");
foreach ($xml_data->children() as $data)
$ns_data = $data->children("http://base.google.com/ns/1.0");
$price = $ns_data->price;
{
    echo "<div class='col-md-4'>";
    echo "<div class='title'>$data->title</div>";
    echo "<div class='image'>$data->price</div>";
    echo "<a href='$data->link' target='_blank'><div class='link'>buy now</div></a>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>

Comment: My pleasure, please send your whole XML code in the question, so I will be able to write a full code for you.

Comment: I edit my answer and test the result. It worked by my end. Please check by yours.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks (due to personal reasons, please change the XML link - thanks). How can I select categories and not show entries without content, please?

Comment: My pleasure, you can check the length of entries with strlen() and if it is less than 1 or 2 character, skip it. Also, please do me a favor and select my answer as final answer. Thanks

Comment: Please change the whole url ;-) Thanks.

Comment: Sure, thanks for repu.