# how to put XML link behind php button

Tags: php, css, xml

I would like to show the content of an xml file in a way that it shows the title, image, price and button with external link to the website.

Construction of the xml:

```
 <title>
  <![CDATA[ here comes the title ]]>
  </title>
  <description>
  <![CDATA[ here you can find the description of the product. ]]>
  </description>
  <link>https://www.linktoproduct.com</link>
  <g:product_type>
  <![CDATA[ brand1 &gt; brand2 &gt; brand3 &gt; brand ]]>
  </g:product_type>
  <g:image_link>https://www.linktoproduct.com/imageproduct.jpg</g:image_link>
  <g:price>
  <![CDATA[ 35.10 EUR ]]>
  </g:price>
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
  <style>
  .title{
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 24px;
   color: seagreen;
   }
  .description{
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 20px;
   color: #bbb;
   }
   .link{
     outline: none;
     color: #fff;
     font-weight: 600;
     font-size: 14px;
     background-color: red;
     border: 1px solid red;
     border-radius: 50px;
     padding: 10px 25px;
     line-height: 24px;
     margin-bottom: 9px;
     transition: 0.3s;
     cursor: pointer;
      }
      .col-md-4 {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 1px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      }  
      @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .col-md-4 {
      width: 33.33333333%;
      float: left;
      }
  </style>

  <?php
  $xml_data =    simplexml_load_file("https://www.website.com/productfeed.xml") or 
  die("Error: Object Creation failure");

  foreach ($xml_data->children() as $data)
  {
 echo "<div class='col-md-4'>";
 echo "<div class='title'>";
 echo $data->title ."<br>";
 echo "</div>";
 echo "<div class='description'>";
 echo $data->description ."<br> ";
 echo "</div>";
 echo "<div class='link'>";
 echo $data->link ."<br> ";
 echo "</div>";
 echo "</div>";

  }

  ?>
```

but it gives me this issue on how to see a button with link to the website opening in a new tab. So not to have the link visible, but have it behind a button.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear (your XML doesn't seem complete, as you are trying to loop in the PHP, but visibly I don't see multiple items in your XML). Please make proper sentences, explain what you want with precision, provide a runnable example and show us what you already have attempted yourself to resolve the problem. Reading [Stackoverflow - How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) could help you.

Comment: How is this problem different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77215524/how-to-show-style-xml-product-feed-into-php? Is this a PHP problem, or a CSS problem?

Comment: The other issue is "how to call the <g:> from an xml into a php file" - this issue here is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer:
replace

```
 echo $data->link ."<br> ";
```

by

```
 echo "<a href='$data->link' target='_blank'>buy now</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly - you wish to have a button to take the user to the relevant URL rather than display the actual URL on the page?! If so then you could include an inline hyperlink that contains a simple button that displays some text or other.

```
foreach( $xml_data->children() as $data ){
    printf('
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="title">%s</div>
            <div class="description">%s</div>
            <div class="link">
                <a href="%s" target="_blank">
                    Click me baby one more time
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>',
        $data->title,
        $data->description,
        $data->link
    );
}
```

Example of how the HTML might look

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="title">Banana</div>
  <div class="description">Curvy Yellow fruit</div>
  <div class="link">
    <a href="https://www.bananalink.org.uk/all-about-bananas/" target="_blank">
      Click me baby one more time
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="title">Apple</div>
  <div class="description">Spherical green fruits loved by teachers</div>
  <div class="link">
    <a href="https://cideruk.com/apple-growers/" target="_blank">
      Click me baby one more time
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah, forgot that...just the mention of button and I missed that